# How do I set a value to its default user agent value?

Tags: css, css-selectors, user-agent

By using the `initial` value, I can set an element's CSS property to its initial value as defined by the specification.

But in some cases, I want to set a CSS property to its initial user agent value instead.

For example, the `appearance` property of a `select` element varies based on what operating system you're using. Its default value is `none`, but most of the time it's then set to `menulist` by the user agent stylesheet, especially on a desktop browser.

So, if I want to set a `select` element back to its default user agent value, how would I do that? Ideally, I could just remove every rule that overrides it, but that's not always a practical option (for example, in a WordPress theme, or when using a third-party library).

Here's a visual example:

https://jsfiddle.net/xqy6zsfk/

A default select element

```
<select id="select1">
<option>appearance: initial;</option>
<select>

<select id="select2">
<option>appearance: unset;</option>
<select>

<select id="select3">
<option>appearance: revert;</option>
<select>

<select id="select4">
<option>apperance: inherit;</option>
<select>
```

```
select
{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#select1
{
    -webkit-appearance: initial;
    -moz-appearance: initial;
    appearance: initial;
}

#select2
{
    -webkit-appearance: unset;
    -moz-appearance: unset;
    appearance: unset;
}

#select3
{
    -webkit-appearance: revert;
    -moz-appearance: revert;
    appearance: revert;
}

#select4
{
    -webkit-appearance: inherit;
    -moz-appearance: inherit;
    appearance: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to set a property back to what is defined in the user agent stylesheet is to use the `revert` value.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert) describes `revert` like this:

> it resets the property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent or to the default value established by the user agent's stylesheet.

The `revert` value is relatively new but is now fairly well supported. According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=revert), over 93% of people use a web browser that supports it, making it somewhat ready for production on cutting-edge websites.

That said, if you need to support older browsers, you should make sure that your web page is still usable when the `revert` rule isn't active. You can do this by temporarily commenting it out or disabling it through the web browser's dev tools.

Comment: Looks like they're planning to add it to Chrome 84. That's a huge step forward!

Comment: Browser support is now 93% according to caniuse. You may update your answer @MikhaD